# IEEEtran bibliography (url)

Tags: bibliographies, ieeetran, overleaf, url

I use the template from IEEE, to be precise, I use **IEEEtran.cls 2015/08/26 version V1.8b**
It should the same as you can download here: https://www.ieee.org/conferences/publishing/templates.html
Direct link: https://www.ieee.org/content/dam/ieee-org/ieee/web/org/pubs/conference-latex-template_10-17-19.zip

I want to add an reference to a site, but I can't find out how to do this. This is the format I use now:

```
@online{NameRef,
author = {Name},
title = {Title},
year = 2019,
url = {https://www.website.com},
}
```

However, when I use it like this, it will only show:

> [2] Name. Title, 2019.
> How can I fix it that it will show the url too?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please tell us which bibliography style you employ at present. And, does your document load the `url` package?

Comment: I'm fairly new to latex, so I don't know for sure this is the answer you are looking for. I load my bibliography with

`\bibliographystyle{unsrt}

\bibliography{bibfile} `

The rest of the file is kept original like in the zip file linked above

Comment: With the `IEEEtran` class it makes sense to use the accompanying bib style `\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}` instead of the standard `unsrt`. `IEEEtran.bst` supports the `url` field.

Comment: Thank you! That worked

Comment: _( @moewe I want to choose your solution as answer but I can't do that (yet)? I tried to do what they say here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers But I don't see the answer option )_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the `IEEEtran` class it makes sense to use the accompanying bibliography style

```
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
```

instead of the standard `unsrt`. `IEEEtran.bst` supports the `url` field out of the box, so the example in the question should work there. (Though `IEEEtran` only knows `@misc` not `@online`.)